# Why do we use the gerund of begin but not end when discussing a range?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds

In colloquial speech, one often hears the use of `the beginning and the end` to denote a range, but you rarely hear them paired in the same form or or the opposite pairing: ie begin and ending, begin and end, beginning and ending.

Comment: Because the noun *end* existed before the like verb and because *begin*, never having been a noun, requires that we use the gerund.

Comment: Do you have any source information on this? If so, please post as an answer to claim your meaningless internet points =).

Comment: Apparently I was incorrect in my first statement (both the verb *end* and the noun came about in linguistic prehistory), but I will still answer it as best I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is essentially a three-parter - why use *beginning*? why use *end*? and why put them together as such? - and so I will answer it accordingly.

1 - Why use *beginning*? why not *the begin and the end*?

Whereas the phrase requires that both the *beginning* and the *end* be nouns, the word *begin* is a verb.  Although it may eventually become a noun as well, there is practically [no history to support this usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20beginning,%20the%20begin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%20beginning;,c0;.t1;,the%20begin;,c0).  Whenever we want the verb *begin* to act as a noun, we typically use the gerund *beginning*.  Ironically, the synonym *start* behaves oppositely, preferring to use simple *start*, rather than *starting*, as the nominal form.

2 - Why use *end*? why not *the beginning and the ending?*

I first hypothesized that the noun *end* came about before the verb.  I can neither prove nor disprove this hypothesis, but it seems likely.  [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=end&searchmode=none) lists the verb *to end* as having come *'from the source of end (n.).'*

If the noun *end* did indeed come about before the verb, then it is not beyond reason that it should be used more than the gerund.  *End* is also shorter than *ending*, which fits with the common feature of language to be simplified wherever possible.

Perhaps there is also some significance in their meanings.  To me it seems that an *ending* spans over a period of time, whereas an *end* is a single point.  If, having seen a movie, I said *'I really liked the end'*, I would mean that everything tied together nicely; if, however, I said *'I really liked the ending'*, I would mean that the final scene were well done.  Since the word *beginning* has no option for these shades of meaning, it still makes sense that we should get *the beginning and the end*.

3 - Why combine them in this order, disallowed from free variation?

That is the nature of an idiom: it seldom wants to change.  One can indeed say *the beginning and the ending*, or even *the begin and the end*, and it will be understood, but something will always feel off to those listeners who have been hearing *the beginning and the end* for their entire lives.

Comment: The OED agrees that the verb _end_ derives from the noun, but this happened before English. So both the noun and the verb are found throughout Germanic, but the verbal form ultimately derives from the noun stem.